# How to call a same parial view on button click in MVC with java script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to call a same view on button click. Actually i need to refresh a view on button click.

Comment: Hello did you tried the solution? It would resolve your problem accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

***Controller:***

```
   public class PartialController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult PartialViewFromButtonClick()
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialViewFromBtnClick");
        }
    }
```

***Partial View Sample:***

```
<h4>Load Partial View</h4>



<style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <table class="table-bordered ">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Search</strong></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="searchkey" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Search Key" />

            </td>
            <td>

                <input type="submit" value="Search" style="font-weight: bold;" />
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
</div>
<br />
```

***The View Where You Like To Load The Partial View:***

***`HTML:`***

```
 <div>
        <button id="btnLoadPartialView" class="btn btn-primary">Load Partial View</button>
 </div>

<div id="loadPartailView">

</div>
```

***`Script:`***

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnLoadPartialView").click(function () {
                $("#loadPartailView").load("/Partial/PartialViewFromButtonClick");
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***Note:*** If you would like to laod partial view with parameter you could try like this
> `$('#loadPartailView').load('/PartialController/PartialViewFromButtonClick?parameter=2095');` Additionally each time when you would load the partial view in this fashion it will autometically refresh the `partial view` itself. No additional things to implement.

Hope it would help you.